# How to support Amharic(አማርኛ) Ethiopian Language in Android OS below 4.3?

Tags: android, fonts, programming-languages, font-face, multilingual

I would like to create an app that support Amharic(አማርኛ) Ethiopian Language. Android Jelly Bean 4.3 supports it but i want to achieve this feature in all version prior to Jelly Bean 4.3.

When I send the SMS in Amharic characters to the Receiver, it's changed to numbers. So Receiver can't read it at all.

How can i achieve? Is there any library or working sample, which will support prior versions of Android OS.

Thanks

Comment: is there no answer to this one ??
i have a similar problem with IOS
www.google.com.et on ur apple.. and it doesnt show up the text...